# Collision detection with bounce

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm making a android game for a school project. I'm familiar with java, but not experienced with making games. In my game a ball is controlled by the player. This ball needs to bounce of of walls.

I've tried this in two ways, but both unsuccessful. First try: I'm able to detect overlap, but not able to detect the side the ball hits.

c = the ball, r = the wall

```
    float closestX = c.center.x;
    float closestY = c.center.y;

    if(c.center.x < r.topLeft.x) {
        closestX = r.topLeft.x; 
    } 
    else if(c.center.x > r.topLeft.x + r.width) {
        closestX = r.topLeft.x + r.width;
    }

    if(c.center.y < r.topLeft.y) {
        closestY = r.topLeft.y;
    } 
    else if(c.center.y > r.topLeft.y + r.height) {
        closestY = r.topLeft.y + r.height;
    }

    return c.center.distSquared(closestX, closestY) < c.radius * c.radius;
```

So I tried a new approach. But this approach is unstable and treats the ball like a square.

cNew = the ball with the next position, cOld = the ball with the current position, r = wall

```
    if (cNew.center.x + cNew.radius >= r.topLeft.x && cNew.center.x - cNew.radius <= r.topLeft.x + r.width)
    {
        if (cOld.center.y + cOld.radius <  r.topLeft.y && cNew.center.y + cNew.radius >=  r.topLeft.y)
        {
            return Side.TOP;
        }
        else if (cOld.center.y - cOld.radius >  r.topLeft.y + r.height && cNew.center.y - cNew.radius <=  r.topLeft.y + r.height)
        {
            return Side.BOTTOM;
        }
    }
    if (cNew.center.y + cNew.radius >= r.topLeft.y && cNew.center.y - cNew.radius <= r.topLeft.y + r.height)
    {
        if (cOld.center.x + cOld.radius <  r.topLeft.x && cNew.center.x + cNew.radius >=  r.topLeft.x)
        {
            return Side.LEFT;
        }
        else if (cOld.center.x - cOld.radius >  r.topLeft.x + r.width && cNew.center.x - cNew.radius <=  r.topLeft.x + r.width)
        {
            return Side.RIGHT;
        }
    }
    return null;
```

I need to combine these two is some way, but I haven't been able to find out how.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide some more code ? What class is handling your ball and what class is handling your walls ? How are the walls saved ? Whats your level ? An array of Walls ? I also made a platformer once upon a time. The player could also walljump there. I made a pixel-and hitbox based sprite class.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't go very carefully with the code (and considering it is your school project, probably I shouldn't be doing your homework), but I believe treating the ball as a square would not have any negative effects if it is just going to bounce off walls. Is there something else you want to do with it?

Your first code is missing out on the fact that the surface of the ball will collide with the wall before its center. You might want to take that into account. And in what sense is your second code unstable?

Some more details would be useful here.

Comment: If the ball gets treated like a square it will bounce even when it doesn't visually hit the wall. The second code sometimes let's the ball through. I can see the flaws I just don't know how to fix them and I'm probably doing this in the wrong way.
Offtopic: My assignment actually is about the physics of the acceleration and friction, not so much the coding.

Comment: Have you tried doing it? So long as the sides of the square circumscribing the ball are parallel to the walls (I'm assuming the wall is rectangular), it should not cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to tell you here how I did : 
for the player(and every enemy as well) you need :

- x
- y
- w
- h

and :

- x velocity
- y velocity

and the following point array(lists) :

outline :

- upper side
- lower side
- left side
- right side
- all together

-all points that are in your ball, every pixel that hasnt alpha=0, for checking collision with walls

Walls :

- walls are given as point array(list). For example, analyze the level image, every black pixel is added

Now, do the following :

- in your class, have a method for moving

there you need the following logic :

```
int miny=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (Point p:walls) { //For every point in the walls
     if (p.x >= (int)x && p.x <= (int)x+w && (int)p.x-(int)x < lower_side.length) {
         try {
              Point p2=lower_side[(int)p.x-(int)x]; //Get the point that is on the same height as the walls point
              if (p.y >= (int)(y+p2.y) && (int)(y+p2.y+yvel) >= p.y && p.y-p2.y-1 < miny) { //Check if you are going to hit the wall, and if it is earlier as the earliest point determined.
                  miny=p.y-p2.y-1d; //Where is the earliest point where this can happen
              }
          } catch (Exception bug) {
              System.out.println(bug);
          }
     }
}
```

apply this to all directions and dimensions.

```
if (miny != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    y=miny; //Set position over the wall
    yvel=-(yvel*0.75); //Bounce off
}
```

**If you have any questions, feel free to comment.**